# Search string for a given word and return a boolean value

Tags: c++, string

I am new in this site and I would like to ask if anyone knows how to solve my question.
I have searched the net for hours but didn't find anything that works for me.
Any help will appreciated.

1) I have to write a function that asks for a word.
2) Add this word into an array.
3) Search a string if a word is matching the word given.
4) Boolean return value if is true or false otherwise.

Here what i done with my function so far. So i believe i am close to it( i need only the for loop to search for the word).

```
bool checkValidTitle( string modules[MODULENO+1]){
    string array[1][20];
    cout<< "Put the module: ";
    cin>> array[1][20]; 
}
```

Comment: [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Comment: Are you sure your question is about C and not C++? The code snipped you listed is a C++ code, not C. For a C++ you can indeed use the std::string::find

Comment: its c++ i dont know why the title didnt display the "++" THANK you for the quick reply

UPDATE : added the "++" :) THANK YOU

Comment: Why have a local array?  You just need one string.

Comment: I need to put the word the user puts into an array

Comment: What is `string` here? A `typdef char* string` or a `std::string`?

Comment: @chris, If you *need* an array, why not just `std::string whateverString [1];`?

Comment: i am confused and also new to it =/ 
the string i want to search for the word that the user puts is: 
string modules[MODULENO+1] = {"", "Maths", "Sciences", "French", "English"};

Comment: i have to put the word in an array. and then check if the word in that array matches any of the words in the string modules.. i tried the std::string whateverString [1]; but was crashed.

Comment: I've have a hard job understanding what you are trying to do but the code you posted is an error because it's is an out of bounds array access. Why do you have to put the word in an array? That doesn't make a lot of sense. I suspect you are misunderstanding what you've been asked to do.

Comment: @jahhaj Write a C++ function, called checkValidTitle, which checks that a given module title is a valid title in the system. The function takes two parameters: an array that stores the module title and a string representing a module title and it has a Boolean return value that is true when the string is present in the array and false otherwise.

Comment: doesn't that says that i need an array that stores the module title? so i need an array for the given word right? =/

Comment: OK, so I don't see anything about putting the word in an array. You need a function like this `bool checkValidTitle(string modules[], string word_to_check)` where word_to_check is the string that the user has entered before you called the function,

Comment: i dont have any( string word_to_check) i think i have to do this in my function as well?

Comment: @chris Yes the string to check is passed into the function.As your description says **two parameters**. The user enters the string outside of the function. That's my reading of it anyway.

Comment: so you are saying that i have to ask the user for the module which will put it in a string?? outside my function. and then my function will take that string and check the array for a matching word?

Comment: @jahhaj thank you so much.. 
i ask the user to put the module. how can i put that word into a string??

Comment: `string word_to_check; cin >> word_to_check;`

Comment: i cannot make this to work =/ i get error LNK2019 unresolved {...}

Comment: Well that sounds like a different question. Open another question and post your code.

Comment: @jahhaj i fixed it.. but now it doesn't return if its true or false.. any ideas?

Comment: not without seeing your code, open a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the function that you are being asked to write

```
bool checkValidTitle(string modules[], string word_to_check)
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= MODULENO; ++i)
    if (modules[i] == word_to_check)
       return true;
  return false;
}
```

Use it like this

```
string modules[MODULENO+1] = {"", "Maths", "Sciences", "French", "English"};
if (checkValidTitle(modules, "Maths"))
   cout << "Maths is valid\n";
else
   cout << "Maths is not valid\n";
if (checkValidTitle(modules, "Russian"))
   cout << "Russian is valid\n";
else
   cout << "Russian is not valid\n";
```

I'll leave you to fill in the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote back in the day a function, what returns a boolean value, if the first string contains the second string:

```
bool contains(const std::string & str, const std::string substr)
{
    if(str.size()<substr.size()) return false;

    for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i++)
    {
        if(str.size()-i < substr.size()) return false;

        bool match = true;
        for(int j=0; j<substr.size(); j++)
        {
            if(str.at(i+j) != substr.at(j))
            {
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(match) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have tested it for some time, it seems to work. It searches with brute force, but i tried to optimize as much as i can.

Using this method you can do this:

```
std::string main_str = "Hello world!";
std::string sub_str = "ello";
std::string sub_str2 = "foo";

bool first = contains(main_str, sub_str); //this will give you true
bool second = contains(main_str, sub_str2); //this will give you false
```

Now i don't really understand, what you want with the array of strings, but i think, with this, you can get the desired output.