# Search a string for a word and return the number corresponding to the number of vector. c++

Tags: c++

Any ideas of this?
(DONE) I want to search my string for a specific word
(DONE) If that word is found
(ANY IDEAS) I want to output the number of vector which is the word in it.

i have this here string modules[MODULENO+1] = {"", "Maths", "Sciences", "French", "English"}; i search this string for a word.. i find that word.. the thing i want is to output the number of the vector which is in.. lets say i am searching for English.. i found that word... now i want to output (( the module English is in vector 4 ))

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements? I have no idea what you're asking for here.

Comment: So are all these words in a vector, or when you say vector do you mean you want to report the index of the word that matched within a string of words?

Comment: It's best to show us what you've tried, and ask for specific help. However, looks like you just want http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Comment: i have this here
  string modules[MODULENO+1] = {"", "Maths", "Sciences", "French", "English"};

i search this string for a word.. i find that word.. the thing i want is to output the number of the vector which is in.. lets sey i am searching for English.. i found that word... now i want to output (( the module English is in vector 4 )) thank you for your replies guys ((how can i put some words in grey backround? )) thanks

Comment: @alex - You should edit your question instead of clarifying the question in your comments.

Comment: if you're just looping through all of the characters in the string, you can increment a "vector" counter variable every time you see a comma.

Comment: @pstrjds just did it.. sorry for that.. i am new here :)

Comment: Go back and read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11710222/445976) to your other question. Instead of returning a boolean you can return the numeric index.

Comment: i tried that but didnt work.. i will try again.. thank you

Comment: `string modules[MODULENO + 1]` in combination with the use of the word "vector" is sending icy chills down my spine. This is wrong on so many levels at once...

Comment: @Blastfurnace i dont get it.. i added the int num so every time counts 1 but the output is 1 every time =/

Comment: anyone knows how to do this with a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied this code from the accepted answer to your other question:

```
bool checkValidTitle(string modules[], string word_to_check)
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= MODULENO; ++i)
    if (modules[i] == word_to_check)
       return true;
  return false;
}
```

If you want the numeric index instead of a boolean, change the function return type and the `return` statements:

```
int getModuleNo(string modules[], string word_to_check)
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= MODULENO; ++i)
    if (modules[i] == word_to_check)
       return i;
  return -1; // some magic value to indicate "not found"
}
```

A possible way to use this function is:

```
string word = "English";
int index = getModuleNo(modules, word);
std::cout << "Module " << word << " is number " << index << '\n';
```

Comment: what i want is to return the number of vector that the module is in. 
i dont think this does it?? =/ thank you so much

Comment: do i need anything like this? 

[link]int getModuleNo( string modules[], string word_to_check){
 
 for (int i=1; i< MODULENO; i++)
  if (modules[i] == word_to_check)
   count ++;

 return count;
}
'code'

Comment: @alex: It's not clear what you mean by "number of vector". This will return the index where the word match is found. If "English" is at `modules[4]` then the function will return the value `4`.

Comment: how can i comment the code with gray background? so i can show you something

Comment: string modules[MODULENO+1] = {"", "Maths", "Sciences", "French", "English"};

Comment: now i search "English" and i want it to output.. "Module english is number 4"  or "module Maths is in number 1"

Comment: i dont want to output the index.. i want output the place where the module is

Comment: @alex: Still not clear what you mean by "place where the module is". You have an array of strings. Do you want to know where the word is found in the array? That would be the index or subscript or place. Do you just want the function to print "Module english is number 4" instead of returning a value?

Comment: Write a C++ function, called getModuleNo, which returns the module number corresponding to a given module title. The function takes two parameters: an array that stores the module title and a string representing a module title and it has a return value that represents the corresponding module title.. It has a precondition: that module title must be a valid title..

Comment: @alex: That is exactly what the above function does after my changes. It returns a value that represents the location in `modules` where `module title` is found.

Comment: how am i going to output the return value?

Comment: @alex: See my updated answer. I added some code to print a message using the return value.

Comment: thank you sooo much.. i didnt see that...i works now but when the last module is selected.. it outputs (random numbers ) and not  ( 4 ) all the other modules are correct

Comment: @alex: I made the function return `-1` when a word is not found because the function has to return some value. You can test the return value and print an error message or take some other action if it returns the "not found" value.

Comment: FOUND IT..WORKS... THANKS TO YOU FRIEND...THAAAANKK YOU SOOO MUCHHH

Comment: I HAD TO ADD THE EQUALS SIGN BEFORE THE MODULENO  

(int i = 1 i <= MODULENO; i++)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use *std::find* to find an element and than *std::distance* to calculate the index of the element.